# WPF storyboard animation changes multiple UI objects instead of one

Tags: wpf, storyboard

#### The issue

Moving styles file injection from `App.xaml` to view breaks animations. Instead of changing a specific element, it changes all the items with the same datatemplate.

#### Setup

`Style.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary .....>

    <Style x:Key="Style"
           TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Viewbox}}}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Orange" /> <----- works as expected, changes the object that is hovered 
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard> <----- not as expected, changes all DataModel datatemplates there is
                             <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                                     Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                     To="2.33" />
                             <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                                     Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                     To="2.33" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>                    
                    <!-- omitted, returns the default value -->                       
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataModel}">
        <Viewbox>
            <Canvas Width="{Binding InitialWidth}"
                    Height="{Binding InitialHeight}">
                <Canvas>
                    <Path Opacity="0.2"
                          x:Name="circle"
                          RenderTransform="{StaticResource DefaultScale}"
                          Style="{StaticResource Style}">   <---- the style in question
                        <Path.Data>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="{Binding Radius}"
                                             RadiusY="{Binding Radius}" />
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                <Canvas>               
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox> 
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`MyView.xaml` where style is used is `UserControl` all `DataModel` objects are under `ItemsControl` if that makes any difference.

```
<UserControl>
    <ItemsControl VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                        Value="{Binding LeftOffset}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                        Value="{Binding TopOffset}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

#### The sole change

The issue appears when moving `<ResourceDictionary Source="Style.xaml" />` from `App.xaml`:

[image]

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Style.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

to `MyView.xaml`

[image]

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Style.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: You Forgot To Send The Codes Related To Myview.Xaml. What You Mean Is That When You Define The Styles At The Application Level, Place The Mouse On Any Of The Circles To Change Only That Circle, But When You Define It At The View Level, It Is Enough To Place The Mouse On One Of The Circles. Take To Apply The Effect To All Of Them. Is It Right?

Comment: Updated.
Answering the question - yes. Style defined in App.xaml - all as expected. Style defined in view - animation applied to all the objects

Comment: I guess the location of `DefaultScale` matters. Its instance is shared in your latter case. I don't know why it doesn't happen in your former case though.